# How to control function called by this.form.submit in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Telerik.MVC extensions and certain controls to not pass data to the controller on events.
Tee dropdown must call  this.form.submit during an OnChange event to register that the user made a selection.

```
function ddl_OnChange(e)
{
    this.form.submit();
}
```

In the controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind()]  ViewModel.Designer model, string ddlDatabase,
            string ddl, string cboTemplate, string command)
{ 
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {.....
```

On the **OnChange**, the value of the **ddl** control is passed through the ddl value.

My problem is, I have multiple dropdown and combos and would like to control the action taken by the controller depending on the choice made. How can I direct the  **this.form.submit();**
to other functions. Also, how can I pass data additional data back to this other method.

Comment: when you call this.form.submit(); the form related to that element will be submitted. If you want to redirect to different method then try using Ajax or specify ID for each form and call the submit method on ID.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
In the script, set the action property:

```
function ddlTable_OnChange(e)
     {

        this.form.action += '\\ddlTable_OnChange';
        this.form.submit();
    }
```

In the controller, create matching function:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ddlTable_OnChange([Bind()]  ViewModel.Designer model, string ddlDatabase,
    string ddlTable, string cboTemplate, string command)
{
    return Index();

}
```